# Getting Multiple Error while Building the NopCommerce Programm

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

Can Microsoft .NET SDK Causes these Errors? (CS0234, CS0236)

I don't know why I Get Many Compilation Errors When Building the NopCommerce Program. Could Somebody Help Me Please?

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Commonn' does not exist in
> the namespace 'Nop.Core.Domain' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?) Nop.Web
> C:\Users\armin\Desktop\nopCommerce_4.50.4_Source\Presentation\Nop.Web\Controllers\CustomerController.cs
> 12 Active

After Cloning a Completed Web Application: I Face With Many Multiple Compilation Errors as above!

Comment: How could we possibly know? Please have a look into [ask] and improve the question.

Comment: Could it be that there is a "n" too many and it should be "Common" instead of "Commonn"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download from [nopCommerce 4.50.4 and all version](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/releases/tag/release-4.50.4)

Also, make sure.[Technology & system requirements](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/installation-and-upgrading/technology-and-system-requirements.html)